# rails activerecord column query

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am new to Ruby on Rails.

I get a simple table whose name is `Loadtest`.

The table have two attributes which are: `testname`, `exectime`.

The table may looks like this :

```
\-------------------------

testname | exectime |

test A | xx-xx-xx |

test B | xx-xx-xx |

\--------------------------
```

I want to get all the entries under `testname`, such as  `["test A", "test B"]`. How could I achieve this?

I could use `Loadtest.find(:all)` to get all the entries in the table and write some codes to form the `testname array`. But is there any direct method like `Loadtest.column[:testname]`?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is ***[pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck)*** method.

```
Loadtest.pluck(:testname)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's the method I've been looking for.